# How to output the name of the calling method using XCGLogger?

Tags: swift5, xcglogger

I have created a `MyLogger` class and it passes parameters to `XCGLogger` to output logs. I have specified `true` for the XCGLogger's `showFileName` and `dateshowFunctionName`, but it always outputs MyLogger's own file name and method name. Is there any way to make it output the caller's file name and method name?

This is the output now.

```
2022/06/17,11:44:54.054 [Debug] [MyLogger.swift] logWrite(level:message:) > New user is comming.
2022/06/17,11:44:54.054 [Warning] [MyLogger.swift] logWrite(level:message:) > Invaild login_name or password. [login_name:marverick] failed 1 times.
2022/06/17,11:44:58.058 [Info] [MyLogger.swift] logWrite(level:message:) > Login success. Hello maverick!
```

What I want is this.

```
2022/06/17,11:44:54.054 [Debug] [Login.swift] top() > New user is comming.
2022/06/17,11:44:54.054 [Warning] [Auth.swift] authCheck(login_name:password:) > Invaild login_name or password. [login_name:marverick] failed 1 times.
2022/06/17,11:44:58.058 [Info] [Main.swift] main(param:) > Login success. Hello maverick!
```

My code is this. It seems a bit long, but I don't know what is causing the problem so I haven't abbreviated much.

```
import Foundation
import SSZipArchive
import XCGLogger

publc class MyLogger: NSObject, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    static public func logWrite(level: LOGLEVEL, message:String) {
        let logSetUp = settings.logger()
        let fileName = createFileName()
        let log = XCGLogger.default
       
        do {
            let folderName = FileManager.default.urls(for:.libraryDirectory,in:.userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("Logs",isDirectory:true)
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folderName!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        catch{
            MyLogger.logWrite(level: .ERROR, message: error.localizedDescription)
        }
       
        let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory,in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("Logs", isDirectory: false).appendingPathComponent(fileName + ".log")
        log.dateFormatter?.dateFormat = logSetUp.dateformat
       
        let autorotateFileDestination = AutoRotatingFileDestination(writeToFile: path, identifier: log.identifier, shouldAppend: logSetUp.shouldappend, maxTimeInterval: logSetUp.targetmaxtimeinterval, targetMaxLogFiles: logSetUp.targetmaxlogfiles)
        autorotateFileDestination.showLogIdentifier = logSetUp.showlogidentifier
        autorotateFileDestination.showFunctionName = logSetUp.showfunctionname
        autorotateFileDestination.showThreadName = logSetUp.showthreadname
        autorotateFileDestination.showLevel = logSetUp.showlevel
        autorotateFileDestination.showFileName = logSetUp.showfilenames
        autorotateFileDestination.showLineNumber = logSetUp.showlinenumbers
        autorotateFileDestination.showDate = logSetUp.showdata
        log.add(destination: autorotateFileDestination)
       
        switch level {
        case .DEBUG:
            log.debug(message)
        case .INFO:
            log.info(message)
        case .WARNING:
            log.warning(message)
        case .ERROR:
            log.error(message)
        }
    }
    
    //other methods here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get an answer, but this code gave me the expected results. I got the caller's information from `#file`, `#line`, and `#function`
parameters and added it as a string.

```
import Foundation
import SSZipArchive
import XCGLogger

publc class MyLogger: NSObject, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    static public func logWrite(level: LOGLEVEL, message:String, file: String = #file, line: Int = #line, function: String = #function) {

        //
        // no change here
        // 
       
        let callerFileName :String = String(file.split(separator: "/").last ?? "")
        let customMessage = "[\(callerFileName):\(line)] \(function) >> \(message)"
        switch level {
        case .DEBUG:
            log.debug(customMessage)
        case .INFO:
            log.info(customMessage)
        case .WARNING:
            log.warning(customMessage)
        case .ERROR:
            log.error(customMessage)
        }
    }
    
    //other methods here
}
```